# Display more than one column of the table only when the condition gets satisfied

Tags: java, mysql, validation, jsp, spring-mvc

I'm looking to display the a list of variables once it satisfies the condition of other variables. For Example: When there are totally 5 variables in a table namely Name, Id, Age , Experience, Salary. First it has to show only Id, Name and Experience. Once if i enter value 3 or more in Experience column then it has to display the other two column(Salary and Age) and submit. Or else when i enter a value less than 3 then it has only store the first 3 variables in the table.Here in the program i have to display the account number details only if i enter the experience as more than 3 or else it has to display the remaining column alone in the database.This action is done in Spring M V C using eclipse in CRUD Operation Any clues?.
I have attached my program code

Bean Class:

```
package com.dineshonjava.bean;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.SecondaryTable;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.validation.constraints.Max;
import javax.validation.constraints.Min;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Pattern;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.Email;
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty;
import com.dineshonjava.validator.Ajay;
@Entity
@Table(name="employees")
@SecondaryTable(name="employeedetails")
public class EmployeeBean {
private Integer id;
@NotEmpty
@Size(min=2,max=20)
private String name;
@NotNull
@Min(18)@Max(90)
private Integer age;
@NotEmpty @Email
private String email;
@NotNull
private Integer salary;
@NotEmpty
private String address;
@NotEmpty
private String bae;
@NotNull
private Integer experience;
@NotEmpty
@Size(min = 6, max = 15)
private String password;
@NotEmpty
@Ajay
private String phone;
@NotNull
@Column(table="employeedetails")
private Integer accno;
public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public Integer getAge() {
    return age;
}
public void setAge(Integer age) {
    this.age = age;
}
public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}
public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}
public Integer getSalary() {
    return salary;
}
public void setSalary(Integer salary) {
    this.salary = salary;
}
public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}
public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
}
public String getBae() {
    return bae;
}
public void setBae(String bae) {
    this.bae = bae;
}
public Integer getExperience() {
    return experience;
}
public void setExperience(Integer experience) {
    this.experience = experience;
}
public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}
public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}
public String getPhone() {
    return phone;
}
public void setPhone(String phone) {
    this.phone = phone;
}
public Integer getAccno() {
    return accno;
}
public void setAccno(Integer accno) {
    this.accno = accno;
}
}
```

Controller Class:

```
package com.dineshonjava.controller;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.validation.Valid;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import com.dineshonjava.bean.EmployeeBean;
import com.dineshonjava.model.Employee;
import com.dineshonjava.service.EmployeeService;
@Controller
public class EmployeeController {
@Autowired
private EmployeeService employeeService;
@RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView saveEmployee(@Valid  @ModelAttribute("command") EmployeeBean employeeBean, 
            BindingResult result) {
if(result.hasErrors()){

            return new ModelAndView("addEmployee");
        }
        Employee employee = prepareModel(employeeBean);
        employeeService.addEmployee(employee);
        Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        model.put("employees",  prepareListofBean(employeeService.listEmployeess()));
        return new ModelAndView("displayEmployee",model);
        }
    @RequestMapping(value = "/saved", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView savedEmployee(@Valid  @ModelAttribute("command") EmployeeBean employeeBean, 
            BindingResult result) {
if(result.hasErrors()){

            return new ModelAndView("addEmployee");
        }
        Employee employee = prepareModel(employeeBean);
        employeeService.addEmployee(employee);
        Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        model.put("employees",  prepareListofBean(employeeService.listEmployeess()));
        return new ModelAndView("displayEmployee",model);
    }
    @RequestMapping(value="/employees", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView listEmployees() {
        Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        model.put("employees",  prepareListofBean(employeeService.listEmployeess()));
        return new ModelAndView("employeesList", model);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView addEmployee(@Valid @ModelAttribute("command")  EmployeeBean employeeBean,
            BindingResult result) {
if(result.hasErrors()){

            return new ModelAndView("addEmployee");
        }
        Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        model.put("employees",  prepareListofBean(employeeService.listEmployeess()));
        return new ModelAndView("addEmployee", model);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/index", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView welcome() {
        return new ModelAndView("index");
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/delete", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView editEmployee(@ModelAttribute("command")  EmployeeBean employeeBean,
            BindingResult result) {
        employeeService.deleteEmployee(prepareModel(employeeBean));
        Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        model.put("employee", null);
        model.put("employees",  prepareListofBean(employeeService.listEmployeess()));
        return new ModelAndView("displayEmployee", model);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/edit", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView deleteEmployee(@Valid @ModelAttribute("command")  EmployeeBean employeeBean,
            BindingResult result) {
      if(result.hasErrors()){
             Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();
             model.put("employee", prepareEmployeeBean(employeeService.getEmployee(employeeBean.getId())));
              model.put("employees",  prepareListofBean(employeeService.listEmployeess()));
            return new ModelAndView("editEmployee", model);
        }
        Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        model.put("employee", prepareEmployeeBean(employeeService.getEmployee(employeeBean.getId())));
        model.put("employees",  prepareListofBean(employeeService.listEmployeess()));
        return new ModelAndView("displayEmployee", model);
    }

    private Employee prepareModel(EmployeeBean employeeBean){
        Employee employee = new Employee();
        employee.setAddress(employeeBean.getAddress());
        employee.setAge(employeeBean.getAge());
        employee.setName(employeeBean.getName());
        employee.setSalary(employeeBean.getSalary());
        employee.setId(employeeBean.getId());
        employee.setBae(employeeBean.getBae());
        employee.setExperience(employeeBean.getExperience());
        employee.setEmail(employeeBean.getEmail());
        employee.setPassword(employeeBean.getPassword());
        employee.setPhone(employeeBean.getPhone());
        employee.setAccno(employeeBean.getAccno());
        employeeBean.setId(null);
        return employee;
    }
    private List<EmployeeBean> prepareListofBean(List<Employee> employees){
        List<EmployeeBean> beans = null;
        if(employees != null && !employees.isEmpty()){
            beans = new ArrayList<EmployeeBean>();
            EmployeeBean bean = null;
            for(Employee employee : employees){
                bean = new EmployeeBean();
                bean.setName(employee.getName());
                bean.setId(employee.getId());
                bean.setAddress(employee.getAddress());
                bean.setSalary(employee.getSalary());
                bean.setAge(employee.getAge());
                bean.setBae(employee.getBae());
                bean.setExperience(employee.getExperience());
                bean.setEmail(employee.getEmail());
                bean.setPassword(employee.getPassword());
                bean.setPhone(employee.getPhone());
                bean.setAccno(employee.getAccno());
                beans.add(bean);
            }
        }
        return beans;
    }
    private EmployeeBean prepareEmployeeBean(Employee employee){
        EmployeeBean bean = new EmployeeBean();
        bean.setAddress(employee.getAddress());
        bean.setAge(employee.getAge());
        bean.setName(employee.getName());
        bean.setSalary(employee.getSalary());
        bean.setId(employee.getId());
        bean.setBae(employee.getBae());
        bean.setExperience(employee.getExperience());
        bean.setEmail(employee.getEmail());
        bean.setPassword(employee.getPassword());
        bean.setPhone(employee.getPhone());
        bean.setAccno(employee.getAccno());
        return bean;
    }
}
```

EmployeeDisplay.jsp:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"
    prefix="form"%>
    <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
        <title>Spring MVC Form Handling</title>
        </head>
    <style>
        .error {
        color: red; font-weight: bold;
    }
        </style>
    <body>
    <h2>Add Employee Data</h2>
        <form:form method="POST" action="/sdnext/save.html">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td align="left" width="20%">EmployeeID: </td>

                    <td align="left" width="40%"><form:input path="id"  readonly="true" size="30"/></td>

                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="left" width="20%">Name: </td>
                    <td align="left" width="40%"><form:input path="name" size="30"/></td>
                    <td><form:errors path="name" cssClass="error"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="left" width="20%">Age: </td>
                    <td align="left" width="40%"><form:input path="age" size="30"/></td>
                    <td align="left"><form:errors path="age" cssClass="error"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="left" width="20%">salary: </td>
                    <td align="left" width="40%"><form:input path="salary" size="30"/></td>
                    <td align="left"><form:errors path="salary" cssClass="error"/></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td align="left" width="20%">Address: </td>
                    <td align="left" width="40%"><form:input path="address" size="30"/></td>
                    <td><form:errors path="address" cssClass="error"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="left" width="20%">Bae: </td>
                    <td align="left" width="40%"><form:input path="bae" size="30"/></td>
                    <td><form:errors path="bae" cssClass="error"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="left" width="20%">Experience: </td>
                    <td align="left" width="40%"><form:input path="experience" size="30"/></td>
                    <td><form:errors path="experience" cssClass="error"/></td>

                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="left" width="20%">Email: </td>
                    <td align="left" width="40%"><form:input path="email" size="30"/></td>
                    <td><form:errors path="email" cssClass="error"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Password: </td>
                    <td><form:password path="password" size="30"/></td>
                    <td><form:errors path="password" cssClass="error"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="left" width="20%">Phone: </td>
                    <td align="left" width="40%"><form:input path="phone" size="30"/></td>
                    <td><form:errors path="phone" cssClass="error"/></td>
                </tr>
                 <tr>
                    <td align="left" width="20%">Accno: </td>
                    <td align="left" width="40%"><form:input path="accno" size="30"/></td>
                    <td><form:errors path="accno" cssClass="error"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                  <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Submit"/></td>
              </tr>
            </table></form:form>
</body>
</html>

EmployeeDisplay.jsp:
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <c:if test="${!empty employees}">
    <table align="left" border="1">
        <tr>
            <th>Employee ID</th>
            <th>Employee Name</th>
            <th>Employee Age</th>
            <th>Employee Salary</th>
            <th>Employee Address</th>
            <th>Employee Bae</th>
            <th>Employee Experience</th>
            <th>Employee Email</th>
            <th>Password</th>
            <th>Phone</th>
            <th>Account Number</th>
            <th>Action Performed</th>
            </tr>
<c:forEach items="${employees}" var="employee">
            <tr>
                <td><c:out value="${employee.id}"/></td>
                <td><c:out value="${employee.name}"/></td>
                <td><c:out value="${employee.age}"/></td>
                <td><c:out value="${employee.salary}"/></td>
                <td><c:out value="${employee.address}"/></td>
                <td><c:out value="${employee.bae }"/></td>
                <td><c:out value="${employee.experience }"/></td>
                <td><c:out value="${employee.email}"/></td>
                <td><c:out value="${employee.password}"/></td>
                 <td><c:out value="${employee.phone}"></c:out>
                 <td><c:out value="${employee.accno}"></c:out>

                <td align="center"><a href="edit.html?id=${employee.id}">Edit</a> | <a href="delete.html?id=${employee.id}">Delete</a></td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </table>
</c:if>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should narrow down the problem. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Unclear what you are asking exactly.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement this in user interface level. Database will have 5 columns. But when you enter only 3 columns, remaining two columns will be null.

Comment: cool. It will be none forever or can i use it in any cost...for example i want to use that remaining columns when i have experience of more than two(when i enter).